# Formato PHP en Email no lo respeta

Tags: php, html5, email

Tengo un sistema en el que envio un correo cuando asigno un trabajo a un empleado, el codigo es el siguiente:

```
$para      = $correo;
            $titulo    = 'Nuevo Servicio';

            $mensaje = '
            <html>
                <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                    <title>Nuevo Servicio</title>
                </head>
                <body>
                    <div>
                    <p>Tienes un nuevo servicio en tu bandeja de entrada, verificalo en el sistema: <b><a href="web.com">web.com</a></b></p>
                    </div>
                </body>
            </html>';

            $cabeceras = 'From: example@web.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: example@web.com' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

            $success = mail($para, $titulo, $mensaje, $cabeceras);
```

Y parece que todo esta bien, pero el correo que llega, se ve de la siguiente manera:

[image]

No respeta para nada mi código HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te falta la cabecera de Tipo de contenido HTML.

```
$cabeceras = 'From: example@web.com' . "\r\n" .
             'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n" .
             'Reply-To: example@web.com' . "\r\n" .
             'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
```

Comment: Genial bro, gracias